# LDAP Search -- Bad Filter

Tags: perl, search, filter, radix, netldap

So I am trying to search LDAP to populate a CSV file.  The User IDs are obtained by parsing a text file.  I want to search the LDAP for the user ID (mailNickname), FName (givenName), LName (sn), "OU", pwdLastSet.  How do I use the filter aspect of search because I keep getting the "bad filter" error.

Thanks for your help.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use xSV;
use Net::LDAP;
use Term::ReadKey;
# use strict;

$debug_on = 1;  # This will enable some debugging messages.

if (defined($ARGV[0])) {
    $input = $ARGV[0];
} else {
    print "No input file specified!  Assuming MKSGroupsoutput.txt...\n";
    $input = "MKSGroupsoutput.txt";
}

if (defined($ARGV[1])) { 
    $output = $ARGV[1];
} else {
    $output = $input . ".csv";
}

open GROUPS, "< $input" or die "ERROR: Can't open input file: '$input'\n";

print "INPUT: $input\nOUTPUT: $output\n";

sub debug {
    if ($debug_on == 1) {
        print "@_";
    }
}

my $csv = Text::xSV->new(
    filename => $output,
    header   => [
    "AccountName", 
    "LastName", 
    "FirstName", 
    "EEID", 
    "SYSGenericAcct", 
    "Notes", 
    "AccessLevel", 
    "AccessCapability", 
    "Owner/Manager",
    "Description", 
    "Created", 
    "Status", 
    "LastStatusChange", 
    "LastPwdChange", 
    "DataSource"
    ],
  );
$csv->print_header();

my ($inputname, $fname, $lname, @name, $uname, $pwordinput, $pword, $domain, $line, $ldap, $bindstring, $root, $pword, $base_dn);
#User driven input to connect to LDAP.  ReadMode 2 keeps password hidden, the reset back to 0.
print "Please enter your Full Name: ";
$inputname = <STDIN>;
print "Please enter your password: ";
ReadMode 2;
$pwordinput = <STDIN>;
ReadMode 0;

#Builds the LDAP CN value from user input. Trims \n off user input values
$inputname = substr($inputname,0,-1);
@name = split(' ', $inputname);
$fname = ucfirst(@name[0]);
$lname = ucfirst(@name[1]);
$pword = substr($pwordinput,0,-1);
$uname = $lname ."\\, " . $fname;
$bindstring = "CN=" . $uname . ",OU=User,DC=hq,DC=name,DC=com";

#LDAP Connection parameters
$base_dn = "OU=User,DC=hq,DC=name,DC=com";
$ldap = Net::LDAP->new('ldap://local', onerror =>'die');
$ldap->bind($bindstring, password => $pword); #Sometimes the BIND fails (1 out of 10 times)
$root = $ldap->root_dse;

#Parses text file
while ($line = <GROUPS>) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ m/^  user  .*/) {
        $line =~ s/^  user.\s//;
        my ($searchoutput, $user, @entries, $entry, $href, $strDomain, $strUsername, $strDN, $arrSplitResponse, $strLName, $strFName, $strUserType);
        $user = $line;
        $user = "mailNickname: " . $user;
        $searchoutput = $ldap->search(filter=>$user,base=>$base_dn); # ERROR HERE
        @entries = $searchoutput->entries;
        foreach $entry ( @entries ) {
            print "DN: ", $entry->dn, "\n"; #NEVER ENTERS THIS LOOP
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you remove `use strict;`? It should ALWAYS be there. Same with `use warnings;`. That might help point out some of your issues.

I see you've set `onerror` which can be okay once you've solved your problems, but I recommend that you don't do that until you've solved all of your problems. Instead, capture the output of your LDAP methods:

```
my $ldap_message = $ldap->bind($bindstring, password => $pword);
die qq(LDAP Error Code: ) . $ldap_message->code if $ldap_message->code;
```

This might help you debug.

---

Okay, enough berating you. Let's get down to your error:

If I remember my `Net::LDAP`, the search is:

```
my $search_obj = ldap->search(base => $base, filter => $filter);
```

where `$base` is a valid LDAP base, and `$filter` is a valid query in LDAP syntax.

Looking at your code:

```
my $user = "mailNickname: " . $user;
my $searchoutput = $ldap->search(filter=>$user, base=>$base_dn); # ERROR HERE
```

It looks like your search query is `mailNickName: david` if `$user` is `david`. That's not a valid LDAP search. It should be

```
my $user = "(mailNickname=$user)"; #Equal sign. Parentheses might be unnecessary
my $searchoutput = $ldap->search(filter=>$user, base=>$base_dn);
```

Notice I can put variable names inside of quotes. It's one of the things I like in Perl. Makes the code easier to read. That might do the trick. Again, capture the output of all of your LDAP methods, and use the *code* method to find out what's causing your error.

Comment: Thank you for explaining strict better. By turning that on, I thought it was breaking my program, I saw all the problems with my code.  I can now connect to the LDAP and filter correctly.  

However, in my output, I still get  Net::LDAP::Entry=HASH(0xe89dd4) output.  By the way my output I am watching is script progress in the command prompt.

How do I stop that from showing?

Comment: Again, this error started showing up:
Please enter your password: Can't call method "bind" on an undefined value at ldaptest.pl line 77, <STDIN> line 2.

Line 77 is my $pwordinput = <STDIN>; and it was working and just stopped.  It is as if the <STDIN> hangs up and does not respond when I hit "Enter." Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: @cquadrini I notice you don't `chomp` your input. When you input from STDIN, you may be getting the LF character at the end of your line. You can do `chomp(my $password = <STDIN>)`, or in two lines. You can put `print qq(Password = "$password");` after you enter your password to see if it's what you think it is. The `qq()` is like using double quotation marks, but you can then use double quotes without having to escape them. Look up `qq` in the [Perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: wouldn't $pword = substr($pwordinput,0,-1); do the same thing?

Comment: @cquadrini You're getting the `HASH(0xe89dd4)` because the return value isn't a scalar, it's an [Net::LDAP::Entry](http://search.cpan.org/~marschap/perl-ldap-0.44/lib/Net/LDAP/Entry.pod). When you get that, `use Data::Dumper;` and then `print Dumper $entry . "\n";` object. That will dump the object. You can see it's structure, but you'll see that it's _blessed_ as a `Net::LDAP::Entry` object. The [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~marschap/perl-ldap-0.44/lib/Net/LDAP/Search.pod#entries) says the output of a `Net::LDAP::Search->entry` is a `Net::LDAP::Entry`, but it's easy to gloss over.

Comment: @cquadrini The advantage of [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) is that it will remove all _input record separator_ characters (by default, it's _NL_) from the end, and if there isn't one, it won't do nothing. `chomp` returns the number of _input record separators_ it removed. 99% of the time, `substr` is the same, but it's that last 1% that'll get you in trouble. Chomp replaced [chop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) back in Perl 4.0. `Chop` is still there, but `chomp` is better for what most people want.

Comment: @cquadrini instead of using `print`, see if you can put `use feature qw(say);` at the top of your program, and use `say "Print this";` instead of `print "Print this\n";`. [Say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) is now preferred over `print` in most cases.

Comment: Chomp() seems to have fixed the <STDIN> issue.

Comment: the entry on 'code'NET::LDAP::Entry is Greek to me.  I did read that when reading CPAN website, but it didn't fully make sense.  Could you explain it further?

Comment: @cquadrini Some Net::LDAP methods return a [Net::LDAP::Message](http://bit.ly/GRL764) object as a result. I know all of these different types of objects can be frustrating, but that's standard OOP. Basically `Net::LDAP::Message` is a _result_ of the `Net::LDAP` command much as a Unix command returns an error code. One of Net::LDAP::Message's methods is `code` which returns an integer. 0 if success, non-0 otherwise. Look at (Net::LDAP:Constant)[http://bit.ly/GRLfT8] to understand these codes.